# No such file or directory PHP error - But the file is there

Tags: php

i receive this PHP Error whenever i try to include a php file in my index.php:

> No such file or directory

At first i include this file at the beginning of the index.php: `require_once("../resources/engine/settings.php");`

And i get no error, but when i include the header file with `require_once($TEMPLATES."/header.php");`

I get that error.

$TEMPLATES is a variable that's declared in settings.php (that is included correctly into index.php).

This is settings.php:

```
<?php

     $BASEURL = "http://localhost/webname";
     $CSSFolder = $BASEURL."/public/css";
     $CSS = $CSSFolder."/style.css";
     $IMGFolder = $BASEURL."/public/img";

     $ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/webname";
     $TEMPLATES = $ROOT."/resources/templates";
     $ENGINE = $ROOT."/resources/engine";

?>
```

Comment: Your missing the double dot preceding the variable call:

`require_once(..$TEMPLATES."/header.php");`

Comment: I receive a syntax error by doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, i always use [dirname](http://php.net/dirname) to get the root path defined, and id suggest you to use that also. If you use this all over the place, you'll faster get rid of all the path traversing confusion that can arise with it.

I find it easier to work with, like this

```
$ROOT = dirname(__FILE__)."/webname";
```

Although they seem to return the same, using `DOCUMENT_ROOT` returns the absolute path of where the script is executing, whereas the `dirname` call is absolute to where the file is located physically.

**Now to address your question:**

An easy way to debug includes like this is to actually just print out the path, which would be `print $TEMPLATES."/header.php"` and check whether that is what you expect it to be, if not, then correct it.

Comment: I used the `print $TEMPLATES."/header.php"` and the path is correct, but i keep receiving the same error even if i use `dirname` instead of `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: if you use dirname, the path to the file will be absolute and correct.  There is something you're not telling, because your code as is, should work.

Comment: You are right, i'm not telling you i'm a moron.

I put `require_once("../engine/settings.php");` in both index.php and header.php.
Sorry guys :( - Anyway i will set your reply as answer because it helped me much :)

Comment: Im glad you found the problem, often having a pause from the code can fix the issue (which seemed like to be the magic thing). I hate having that kind of problems myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

And yes, using of `dirname(__FILE__)` is much better, because your site root could not always be the same as the server's DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Also on some configs nice to use als `realpath()` to resolve some symlinks.